# CSS Textarea and Div side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my textarea and div to be side by side and have the run button underneath but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

The output looks like this:

http://codeeplus.net/test.php

CSS:

```css
  .CodeMirror { height: 400px; width: 500px; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
  .CodeMirror-scroll { max-height: 400px; }
  .CodeMirror pre { padding-left: 7px; line-height: 1.25; }
  #drawing { border: 1px solid #555555; float:left; width:480px; height: 400px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; padding: 10px; width:50%; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000;">
<div style="float:left">
    <textarea align="left" style="overflow:auto;" id="demotext" name="textarea">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Learning HTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I'm learning HTML! This is my first line of code!</p>
    </body>
</html></textarea>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<div id="drawing" style="text-align:left;padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="run" value="Run" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is totally invalid. All your elements should be within the body section (div, textarea, input).

Comment: Guys, all the stuff inside the other html tags are part of the text area. Look at the output on the link. This is used via iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use two div's one to wrap around your text area and one to wrap around your other div. This way you can just use `float: left;` to put them both side by side :)

Comment: Thats what I thought too so I tried that and I updated the code with what I have set for float left but checkout the output on the link. Not sure why D:

Comment: Have you wrapped your whole page inside a div called content or something?

Comment: I can see you are using absolute in this line of code: position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; padding: 10px; width:50%; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000; because the window is just 50% its to small to contain all the other elements in a float: left position...

Comment: If you zoom in and out on your browser you can see how all the other elements change, besides your sourrounding div with 50% width on... if you soom far enough out, they align in a float: left position :)

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. How would this be fixed though?

Comment: Either, by making your textfield have a % width of 25% and your div a % width of 25%. OR by simply making the entire wrap box big enough for both in pixels :)

Comment: Ohhhhh. I understand now! Thankyou :) Its working now! :D Btw do you know how to make it so when I type so much in the textbox and it goes to the end of the set width it will start a new line?

Comment: `<div style="left: 10px; top: 10px; padding: 10px; width:1000px; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000;">` Here is one method :)

Comment: I have never come across that before so I'm not sure, I might look into it actually...

Comment: You might wish to take a look at this: http://perplexed.co.uk/596_expanding_textarea_as_you_type.htm for that

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: inline-block;` property here, on the elements you want to align in one line:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Online Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sEtdb/)

The default value for `div` tags is `display:block;`

#### EDIT 1:

I have checked your page. The `div` that you're trying to align in is not aligning, because your parent div has `width:50%` and it's simply not fitting in there. Try changing it to, let's say `width:100%` and see that it really works!

#### EDIT 2:

Also remember, that if you use `padding`, as you apparently do on your page, it's affecting the actual (final) `width` of the element. For example, if you set the parent *div*'s `width: 1200px` and *padding* as `padding:10px;`, then the actual *div's* size will be `1160px`, cutting `10px` on each side.

Comment: Hmm..I never thought of that, I like your idea but for some reason this isn't working, can you check it out via development console?

Comment: Edited my answer, please take a look!

Answer (score 1):

your code seems have many problems :), I made some changes:

- remove `float:left;` from `div`s
- set `display:inline-block;`
- add `clear:both` tag before `button`
- remove `width:50%;` and `height:50%` form first `div`

look at new HTML:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
    <textarea align="left" style="overflow:auto;" id="demotext" name="textarea">
    <head>
        <title>Learning HTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>I'm learning HTML! This is my first line of code!</p>
    </body>
</textarea>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block">
<div id="drawing" style="text-align:left;padding:10px;"></div>
</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
<input type="button" id="run" value="Run" />
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle is here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/Cp3d5/)

Comment: I think questioner should start learning from manipulating plain and specific content, to grasp the basic idea of HTML & CSS. +1 For providing concrete example.